# Button goes under a layout which is defined below it

Tags: android, layout, floating-action-button

Hi I have a fab button in my layout "addfab" which is showing correctly in most phones but in android 4.4 kitkat hides under a Relative layout that is defined under it in xml.They both are defined to be below one object Here is my xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:weightSum="1">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bar1"

    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addfab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar1"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_green"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pic"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_gol"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:civ_border_width="5dp"
        app:civ_shadow="false"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="5"
        app:civ_shadow_color="#9e9e9e"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What should I do? Why androids act differently?

Comment: hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/41032921/2993388

Comment: But I use RelativeLayout not CoordinatorLayout

Comment: @atefe `RelativeLayout` doesn't seem to be the best choice in there since you have a layout which has Fab Button-`AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`. The reasonable way is to design that using `CoordinatorLayout` since it allows more functionality and the best behavior.

Comment: In newer versions, it is working because elevation is set to 02. On older devices, there's no elevation. So, you have to update your layout and add the FAB at the end of the file. RelativeLayout was placed after the FAB in your XML. So, android will render the RelativeLayout above the FAB.

Comment: Thanks everyone it helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `RelativeLayout`, use `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
//Toolbar here
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

// your fab and relativelayout here
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As the root level tag. You'll be able to anchor it(The `FloatingActionButton`) to the views you want by using:

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/viewpager"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

Attributes. This also allows you to have more functionality like hiding `Toolbar` or etc in future. You'll also need to change-remove old `RelativeLayout`'s attributes later in order to use `CoordinatorLayout`.

**Take a look:** https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons