# What's the minimum Api version for using FloatingActionButton in Android?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I need to know what api version support the fab element in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FloatingActionButton is available to API 7 (android 2.1), as it was added to the Android Support library in 2015: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

To use the fab using the support library you can use the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753179/6543020

Answer (score 3):

The [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for the Design Support Library release, of which `FloatingActionButton` is a part of, states the following:

> With a little help from the new Android Design Support Library, we’re bringing a number of important material design components to all developers and to all Android 2.1 or higher devices.

Android 2.1 is API level 7, so apps targeting 7 and above can use `FloatingActionButton`

Answer (score 0):

And analogue from **shamanland** - [FAB Library](https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button) also works from the Android 2.1, `API level 7`.

Answer (score 0):

mine api it support is 7+. if i am not wrong.